# How to show element only if other element contains something using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My guess is what I want to achieve should be easy, but due to my lack of knowledge of front-end development, I cannot manage to solve issue. Have a page that works with AJAX-filters that users can select. Filters that are currently applied show up within `<div>`  with `id=current-filters`.

HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="current-filters-box">
    <div style="margin-bottom: 15px">
        <strong>Current filters:</strong>
        <div id="current-filters">
        <!-- here every single applied filter is displayed -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Need to hide the the entire DIV `current-filters-box` in case no filter is applied.

The page uses a Javascript file, **bundle.js** which is massive, but contains the following line:

```
s=document.getElementById("current-filters")
```

Therefore tried the following if-statement to hide the DIV:

```
if(s.length<1)$('#current-filters-box').hide()
```

and

```
if(s=0)$('#current-filters-box').hide()
```

But this does not seem to have any effect. Can someone tell, what I did wrong?

[Demo of page can be found here](https://www.shorttermprograms.com/programs/)

EDIT: this is what the HTML looks like when filters are applied:

```
<div id="current-filters-box">
<div style="margin-bottom: 15px">
    <strong>Current filters:</strong>
    <div id="current-filters">
        <div class="badge-search-public">
            <strong>Humanities &amp; Languages</strong> <span class="x" data-property="disciplines" data-value="4" onclick="filter.removeFilter(this)">×</span>
        </div>
        <div class="badge-search-public">
            <strong>January</strong> <span class="x" data-property="months" data-value="1" onclick="filter.removeFilter(this)">×</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a solution but generally do not use variables that are defined in bundled scripts or libraries, but rather create your own variable for your own use. If bundle ever changes you will have this very weird bug that noone will be able to solve

Answer (score 1):

Both of your conditions are incorrect or I would say they are not doing what you think they do.
`s.length` will always prints undefined so instead of `s.length<1` you could use `s.children.length`

and the second one is not a condition rather it is an assignment

```
s==0 // condition
s=0 //assignment
```

the correct condition for your requirement would be

```
if(s.children.length<1){
```

I have assigned snippets for illustration.

#### Without filters

```js
s = document.getElementById("current-filters")
console.log(s.children.length);
if (s.children.length < 1) {
  $('#current-filters-box').hide(1000)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="current-filters-box">
  filter box
  <div style="margin-bottom: 15px">
    <strong>Current filters:</strong>
    <div id="current-filters">
      <!-- here every single applied filter is displayed -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Without filters

```js
s = document.getElementById("current-filters")
console.log(s.children.length);
if (s.children.length < 1) {
  $('#current-filters-box').hide(1000)
}
```

```html
<div id="current-filters-box">
  <div style="margin-bottom: 15px">
    <strong>Current filters:</strong>
    <div id="current-filters">
      <div class="badge-search-public">
        <strong>Humanities &amp; Languages</strong> <span class="x" data-property="disciplines" data-value="4" onclick="filter.removeFilter(this)">×</span>
      </div>
      <div class="badge-search-public">
        <strong>January</strong> <span class="x" data-property="months" data-value="1" onclick="filter.removeFilter(this)">×</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: For some reason though, no matter how many filters I apply, the children.length always remains 0 when I use s.children.length.

Comment: Can you also add the possible filters in your current-filters div so that I can modify my answer

Comment: I have added the HTML when filters are applied (two in this case). Thank you for your help.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber the code is perfectly working for with and without filters. Might be you are executing `s.children.length` in an ajax callback before applying the filters.

Comment: You are right, your code works fine. For some reason I cannot get it to work with the rest of my code. There are ajax-requests every time a filter is selected, but I can't spot anything like `s.children.length` in them.

Comment: try to add or look into the code for how you are making ajax-requests and how you are using s.children.length so that you can debug the issue

Comment: I cannot seem to figure it out. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
if( $('#current-filters').is(':empty') ) {
    $('#current-filters-box').hide()// or $('#current-filters-box').css("display","none")

    }
```

Comment: Hiding it works like this. The problem I now have that it remains hidden even when filters are applied. I tried with `else ($('#current-filters-box').show())` but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing an assignment, try..

```
if (s.children.length)
```

Comment: For some reason this always returns 0, no matter how many filters I apply.

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla JavaScript, you can check if the `current-filters` div is empty or not and toggle the parent div `current-filters-box` like this:

```
s= document.getElementById("current-filters");
t= document.getElementById("current-filters-box");

if(s.children.length<1) {
    t.style.display = 'none';
    // t.style.visibility= 'hidden'; <<-- use this if you want the div to be hidden but maintain space
}
else {
    t.style.display = 'block';
    // t.style.visibility= 'visible'; <<-- use this if you used visibility in the if statement above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding your own variable which counts or maintains your applied filters, e.g.

```
var applied_filter_count = 0;
```

at every time filter is applied

```
applied_filter_count++;
if(applied_filter_count) {
   $('#current-filters-box').show()
}
```

and at every time filter is removed

```
applied_filter_count--;
if(!applied_filter_count) {
   $('#current-filters-box').hide()
}
```

and by default `current-filters-box` should be `display:none`